# Unknown series of exceptions when importing Colyseus library and run on browser

Tags: javascript, exception, colyseus

I have a problem like so:
I was trying to use Colyseus in a project, so I tried to import it as suggested by the docs:
`import * as Colyseus from "../library/colyseus/colyseus.js"`
It threw this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Colyseus.Client is not a constructor`
This is where it threw the error:
`let client = new Colyseus.Client(connectionUrl)`
I searched here and there but there's no clear answer for it.
Can someone suggest me some solutions? I'm relatively new to JS.
P/s: I imported the js file as module in the index.html file:
`<script defer src="./logic/script.js" type="module"></script>`

I've tried:

- Import via require: threw `ReferenceError: require is not defined`
- Import without define as module and import via require: still `ReferenceError: require is not defined`
- Reinstall library: tried, still throwing error `Uncaught TypeError: Colyseus.Client is not a constructor`